# Playing remote audio files over SSH

Tags: ssh, audio, remote, streaming, wav

I am connected to a machine via SSH and I often need to listen to WAV files on that machine. I usually open another terminal window and do `ssh host 'cat /path/to/sound.wav' | aplay`, but that's tedious since I have to enter my password every time (I cannot use public-key authentication) and the file paths are long.

What I would like to do is start `magic-command` on my local computer, and then whenever I need to listen to a remote file, run `play-locally sound.wav` from the remote shell and hear the sound from my speakers. Is this possible?